# What could be causing this odd behavior with ColumnTransformer? [Python/sklearn]

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Below i have some code which I can't figure why it is producing the results it is.

I am trying to work with a `ColumnTransformer` and am having some issues getting the right results.

The example I have is a bit odd, but it's the simplest reproducible example I could get. I've tried to reduce the example further but every time I try to, it seems like i lost the issue so my apologies if the example is larger than it needs to be.

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np

samples = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 'Education', 7432, 2008.0, np.nan, 25.0, 6.0, 20.0, np.nan, 1019.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                     0.5406408174555976, 0.8412535328311812, -0.8660254037844385, -0.5000000000000004, 0.0, 1.0, 2016,
                     0.0, 1.0],
                    [9, 0, 0, 'Office', 27000, 2010.0, np.nan, 25.0, 6.0, 20.0, np.nan, 1019.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                     0.5406408174555976, 0.8412535328311812, -0.8660254037844385, -0.5000000000000004, 0.0, 1.0, 2016,
                     0.0, 1.0],
                    [3, 0, 0, 'Education', 23685, 2002.0, np.nan, 25.0, 6.0, 20.0, np.nan, 1019.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                     0.5406408174555976, 0.8412535328311812, -0.8660254037844385, -0.5000000000000004, 0.0, 1.0, 2016,
                     0.0, 1.0],
                    [7, 0, 0, 'Education', 121074, 1989.0, np.nan, 25.0, 6.0, 20.0, np.nan, 1019.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                     0.5406408174555976, 0.8412535328311812, -0.8660254037844385, -0.5000000000000004, 0.0, 1.0, 2016,
                     0.0, 1.0],
                    [4, 0, 0, 'Education', 116607, 1975.0, np.nan, 25.0, 6.0, 20.0, np.nan, 1019.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                     0.5406408174555976, 0.8412535328311812, -0.8660254037844385, -0.5000000000000004, 0.0, 1.0, 2016,
                     0.0, 1.0],
                    [1, 0, 0, 'Education', 2720, 2004.0, np.nan, 25.0, 6.0, 20.0, np.nan, 1019.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                     0.5406408174555976, 0.8412535328311812, -0.8660254037844385, -0.5000000000000004, 0.0, 1.0, 2016,
                     0.0, 1.0],
                    [2, 0, 0, 'Education', 5376, 1991.0, np.nan, 25.0, 6.0, 20.0, np.nan, 1019.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                     0.5406408174555976, 0.8412535328311812, -0.8660254037844385, -0.5000000000000004, 0.0, 1.0, 2016,
                     0.0, 1.0],
                    [6, 0, 0, 'Lodging/residential', 27926, 1981.0, np.nan, 25.0, 6.0, 20.0, np.nan, 1019.7, 0.0, 0.0,
                     0.0, 1.0, 0.5406408174555976, 0.8412535328311812, -0.8660254037844385, -0.5000000000000004, 0.0,
                     1.0, 2016, 0.0, 1.0]])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

scaler = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[("cat", categorical_transformer, [0, 1, 3, 4])])
print(scaler.fit_transform(samples[:5]))
print(scaler.fit_transform(samples[:6]))
```

So, for the `samples[:5]` array subset, I get the following result:

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

This is what I expected and got the same.

However when I do the transformation on the `samples[:6]` array subset

I get this

```
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (0, 6)    1.0
  (0, 7)    1.0
  (0, 14)   1.0
  (1, 5)    1.0
  (1, 6)    1.0
  (1, 8)    1.0
  (1, 12)   1.0
  (2, 2)    1.0
  (2, 6)    1.0
  (2, 7)    1.0
  (2, 11)   1.0
  (3, 4)    1.0
  (3, 6)    1.0
  (3, 7)    1.0
  (3, 10)   1.0
  (4, 3)    1.0
  (4, 6)    1.0
  (4, 7)    1.0
  (4, 9)    1.0
  (5, 1)    1.0
  (5, 6)    1.0
  (5, 7)    1.0
  (5, 13)   1.0
```

I have no clue what this data format is. I want to figure out why my scaler is returning this type of data when I add that extra sample.

Comment: What you are seeing is a sparse representation. When the sample size gets larger, it gets more efficient to store these binary matrices in sparse format. Try `scaler.fit_transform(samples[:6]).todense()` to see the more familiar representation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, its just the same answer but represented in sparse representation. One way is converting the sparse array to dense using `todense()`.

Another way is setting the `sparse=False` in the `OneHotEncoder` itself.

```
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False))])

scaler = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[("cat", categorical_transformer, [0, 1, 3, 4])])
```

Remember convert the output as dense comes with a higher computation and memory cost. If you are working on a large dataset, it is recommended to keep it as a sparse array itself.